# Docker stack deploy stop container first

Tags: docker, deployment, stack, kill, sigterm

I cannot find a solution on the net: I automatically (re-) deploy my stack using

```
docker stack deploy -c compose.yml atu
```

but it seems, the service contianers are all **killed** immediatly, which causes problems, because they cannot shutdown properly / gracefully.

Is there a way to first try **stop** (SIGTERM 15) the containers that are to be updated?

Best regards

Comment: If you exec into a container and send a sigterm to pid 1, does it exit gracefully?

Comment: yes, maually stopping causes the Tomcat to shutdown properly; of course, the service monitorring the stopped container notices the status change and just starts a new Container. It is only a problem using the "docker stack deploy" method since it seems to use kill -9, which does not allow the proper shutdown. I could probably write a script which stops all containers in advance, but then i would always have to stop ALL Services (Containers), even those which would not have been updated due to "no changes"...